# Compare column values of different rows Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I want to compare row value of a column with different rows of one other column in Spotfire.

Requirement is whenever Issue ID is on Hold, its childIds also need to be on hold. Seems to be a quick fix however I am stuck around this
Please refer the screenshot

Thanks in Advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Add Data Tables section, and select the name of the original data table in the section titled "From Current Analysis", you can add a second Data Table based off the original data.

Then go to Edit, Data Table Properties, and go to the Column Matches tab -- delete the current column matches (Presumably it matched "Issue ID" to "Issue ID" etc), and then add a new Column Match where your original table has "Issue ID" selected, and the other has "Parent ID" selected.

At this point, you can make a cross table based off of the original table, where Issue ID and Parent ID are along the Vertical Axis.  In your aggregate, add the following code (substituting the name of your second table where it says "Parent"):

```
If(Max([Status]) is null, Max([Parent].[Status]), Max([Status]))
```